# jQuery hover selector filter

Tags: jquery

I have tried to find out this on jQuery documentation but I haven't sort it out.

What I am trying to achieve is that when I am hover ".box" the ".inside-box" appears but I only want the one inside the box I am hover and not all of them.

This is a simplified version of the code.

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".box").hover(
         $("this").filter($(".inside-box")).toggle();
        );
    });
```

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  width:30%;
  margin-left:20px;
  background-color:gray;
  color:white;
 }

.inside-box {
  display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
   <div class="inside-box">hi</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <div class="inside-box">hi</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <div class="inside-box">hi</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your JS syntax is incorrect as the `hover()` event handler needs to be placed inside an anonymous function. Also, if the `.inside-box` elements are hidden the `.box` elements will have no height/width. This means that it will not be possible to cause a `hover` event on them as they take up no space in the DOM. To fix that you need to set a `height` or `min-height` in CSS, or provide some default content outside of the `.inside-box` element.

To achieve the toggle on hover you don't need to use any JS code at all. You can use the :hover` pseudo selector in CSS, like this:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border: 1ps solid red;
}
.inside-box {
  display: none;
}
.box:hover .inside-box {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">a
  <div class="inside-box">hi</div>
</div>

<div class="box">b
  <div class="inside-box">hi</div>
</div>

<div class="box">c
  <div class="inside-box">hi</div>
</div>
```